# Trigger data-target after dropdown selection is made

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, selection

I'm trying to trigger the `data-target="#language-change"` after a user makes a selection from the dropdown. Let's say for example the language chosen is Spanish.

The #language-change is linked to a modal.

This is my HTML code:

```
<div class="my-select">
    <select name="setting-dropdown" class="application-default">
        <option data-toggle="modal" data-target="#language-change" value="EN" selected="english"> English US </option>
        <option data-toggle="modal" data-target="#language-change" value="GB">English GB</option>
        <option data-toggle="modal" data-target="#language-change" value="ES">Español</option>
        <option data-toggle="modal" data-target="#language-change" value="FR">Français</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

My Basic JavaScript Code:

```
// Modal is triggered after a language is selected.
$('.my-select>select').change(function(){
    if ($(this).val() == 'ES').data("target").show()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean this?

```
$('.my-select>select').change(function(){
    if ($(this).val() == 'ES')
          $($('.my-select>select option:selected').attr("data-target")).show()
});
```